# Codeigniter:array to string conversion solution

Tags: codeigniter

Message:

> Array to string conversion

Filename: `models/db_get.php`

```
function get_where_conditions1($tb,$where)
{           
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->from($tb);
    $this->db->join("restaurants", $tb.".".'restaurant_id = restaurants.id',"LEFT");
    $this->db->where_in('branches.'.'$where');
    $this->db->order_by('branches.id','desc');
    $query=  $this->db->get()->result_array();
    $out=array_unique($query);    
    return  $out;      
}
```

Comment: please post how to call this function with details parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function $where must be array but don't know its type.

I think problem is in line  $this->db->where_in('branches.'.'$where');
And It should be $this->db->where_in('branches',$where);